# Php code and html within echo

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I'm writing a if statement in which a button needs to show if the cart is empty. 
For this button I need to get the form key of the product for the `data-url`
So something like this:

```
<a href="#" data-url="checkout/cart/add/product/59/form_key/<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>/" class="btn btn-success">Order</a>
```

As mentioned above I need to wrap this button in an if statement, so something like this:

```
 <?php
    $_helper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
    if (1 > $_helper->getItemsCount()) {
    echo '<a href="#" data-url="checkout/cart/add/product/59/form_key/<?php echo Mage::getSingleton(\'core/session\')->getFormKey(); ?>/" class="btn btn-success">Order</a>';
    }
    else {
        '<p>hello</p>';
    }
    ?>
```

But obviously I can't have php echo within echo. Can anybody point me in the right direction of how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dot/period to connect the pieces of your string, like this:

```
echo '<a href="#" data-url="checkout/cart/add/product/59/form_key/' . Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() . '" class="btn btn-success">Order</a>';
```